# Render SolidJS in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, solid-js

Is there a way to render a `Solid-JS` App (not just a single Component) in `React`?

I've tried importing `react-solid-bridge` and adding the `Solid-JS` App as a route in `React`.  Wrapped the Route in `ReactToSolidBridgeProvider` and used only the `convertToReactComponent` versions of the `Solid-JS` App's child components.

I keep getting "'React' must be in scope when using JSX"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74374764/how-to-use-react-and-solid-js-together/74375675#74375675

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  I can't even get it to build.  Far less, have routing conflicts.  Furthermore, I don't need to route within the SolidJS app.  It's simply an App component with 2 child components, Header and Main.

Comment: It was to give you an idea. You can use this for an MVP https://stackblitz.com/edit/hr-meheraj-vite-react-rr54iq?file=src%2FApp.jsx

Comment: That's a great resource.  However it doesn't work in my codebase as it requires `vite`.